# my program stop working only in once PC (when store picture for second time)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I developed program and tried it on multi PCs, it works perfectly in some of them.

There are 2 PCs with `32 bit`, which have given stop working error.

I upgraded one of them into `64 bit`, but still has the same problem!

The error appeared at the same moment:

1. I choose picture from computer then it will shown at picture box
2. I save data on DB (data include text and picture (ole object))
3. Then I try add new record and choose new picture the Error message come (`program stop working`).

---

program developed using visual basic.net by Visual Studio and access DB

the code of showing picture :

```
        Dim opf As New OpenFileDialog

        opf.Filter = "Choose Image(*.JPG;*.PNG;*.GIF)|*.jpg;*.png;*.gif"

        If opf.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            nameOfFile = opf.FileName
            PicBox.Image = Image.FromFile(opf.FileName)

        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If it just crashes out of your application, you might want to handle any exceptions. Once you handle the exception you can messagebox the error and it might give you an idea why the application has a problem.
As a guess it might be an issue with 32bit/64bit drivers but best to see why application has the issue first.

Comment: I write the try catch and put the messageBox shown but no Message box was appear just stopped working!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that @Dennis suggested.

```
Try
   Dim opf As New OpenFileDialog

    opf.Filter = "Choose Image(*.JPG;*.PNG;*.GIF)|*.jpg;*.png;*.gif"

    If opf.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        nameOfFile = opf.FileName
        PicBox.Image = Image.FromFile(opf.FileName)

    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

I would guess that the error is more likely in the Save code. If this does not produce a MessageBox then try the same thing on the save code.

If this solves your problem pleas accept @Dennis's answer because it was his idea.

Comment: and the save data aleady has try catch and  MessageBox.Show foe exception but nothing happen!

Comment: @AmaniAmeen - Also check the Windows Event Viewer.  There may be some helpful information there.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I found 2 error :
Application: VB1.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
   at System.Windows.Forms.FileDialogNative+IFileDialog.Show(IntPtr)
   at System.Windows.Forms.FileDialog.RunDialogVista(IntPtr)
.......................

Comment: second error :
Faulting application name: VB1.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0xd858eab9
Faulting module name: DUI70.dll, version: 6.3.9600.17415, time stamp: 0x54503a46
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00060a6f
Faulting process id: 0x18f0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d4d81b7fd5a134
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\tttt\VB1.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\DUI70.dll
Report Id: 316b658a-440f-11e9-973a-40167ed342bd
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: